# How to install mpfr (gmp) in R on Fedora?

Tags: r, fedora

I have R installed on fedora with dnf.

Also I installed gmp and gmp-devel with dnf.

In R I did,

```
> install.packages('Rmpfr')
```

But then I get an error,

```
configure: error: GNU MP not found, or not 4.1.4 or up, see http://gmplib.org
```

Comment: It is _always_ the same. You need the _run time library_ as well as the _headers_ to compile from source.  Just how you found R to be installed, you now need to look for `libgmp*`.

Comment: libgmp is in /usr/lib64 Also I installed with dnf gmp and gmp-devel.

Comment: Try `install.packages("Rmpfr", dependencies=TRUE)` and let us know how it goes.

Comment: @ODelibalta Wrong answer. He doesn't have the headers.

Comment: @ericjOk, that means you have the _run-time_ package and you still need the _header_ package (usually called `libfoo-dev` or some variant) to _compile_ against the runtime.  The line you quoted is just one from a larger context which you will understand better over time -- it was basically `configure` telling you that without the _development headers_ no compilation could occur.

Comment: Do I have to install R-devel?

Comment: That has nothing to do with it.  You may need a more experienced R user in your vicinity.  Any colleagues you can lean on?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Fair enough. Try this `install libgmp3-dev` in console ... I use R studio in ubuntu and so far my experience has been that whenever I send the dependencies=TRUE flag, it installs everything it needs but it may not be the solutions in this case.

Comment: No, I am afraid not.

Comment: @ericj Maybe try the r-sig-fedora list then for help with that platform.  Seems like most of us here are on Ubuntu or Debian, sorry.  And there it just works.

Comment: OK, thank you very much!

Comment: Indeed, it simply works on ubuntu. I installed libgmp3-dev first.